# SSL is not working in wp_login.php form action URL

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I have a problem with SSL and Wordpress site URL. All pages and wp_admin works fine except the wp_login.php page.

In wp_login.php page, Login with the wrong credential is not throwing any error. And with right credential not allow to access wp_admin panel because of the action URL in login form is with HTTP and WordPress required https.

When I define `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` to true in wp_config.php file then my WordPress site goes to redirect loop.

I deactivated all the plugins and changed theme also. but it doesn't make any difference.

Here I have use `WordPress HTTPS (SSL)` plugin to secure admin panel from users. Below is the URL of that plugin.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/

Also, my site is loaded with ssl, since my `site_url` and `home_url` don't have ssl. When I'm trying to print `site_url()` it returns with ssl with url.